# Springboot actuator endpoint is throwing a 404 but all endpoints are working fine without actuator prefix

Tags: spring-boot-actuator

Spring boot application has been configured fine using the actuator dependency. Still i can not see /actuator endpoint being invoked in the console logs at application startup.

I assume once the application is started the endpoints which should work are as below-

```
http://localhost/actuator
http://localhost/actuator/health
```

However i can see all the endpoints but /actuator in the console at application startup and these are working fine from browser when invoked directly without /actuator prefix.

`Mapped "{[/manage/beans || /manage/beans.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke() 2023-12-24 19:46:41 - Mapped "{[/manage/configprops || /manage/configprops.json],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()`

I have already tried by adding actuator endpoint in spring security configuration as well but it is always throwing 404

Please let me know what can be possibly wrong here to make sure actuator works as expected.

Also added the management endpoint configurations as below-

[screenshot from configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LMVn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the spring docs for the version i am using and found that below dependency is needed in order to get this link worked upon-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>            
</dependency>
```

After adding the dependency the /actuator link worked.

Here is the documentation link for the spring version 1.4

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready